# How to include the toctree in the sidebar of each page

Tags: python-sphinx, sidebar, toctree

I'm generating html documentation in Sphinx.

How do I modify the sidebar for each of the html pages in my document so that they include the toctree?  By default the toctree only seems to display in the `master_doc` page, and only in the main area instead of the sidebar.

Is there an easy way to do this?  I'll be using readthedocs to host the generated documentation, so I would prefer to avoid the use of any third-party plugins, unless they are also available on readthedocs.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You can customize your html sidebar in `conf.py`.

The default html sidebar consists of 4 templates:

```
['localtoc.html', 'relations.html', 'sourcelink.html', 'searchbox.html']
```

In `conf.py` you could change localtoc.html to globaltoc.html like this:

```
html_sidebars = { '**': ['globaltoc.html', 'relations.html', 'sourcelink.html', 'searchbox.html'] }
```

Since this in the end this will be used in HTML files, this should work on ReadTheDocs.

Answer (score 11):

Including the 'globaltoc.html' has a drawback in that it doesn't show both the global and local toc for the page you're viewing.

It appears that others were irked about this limitation and resulted in the subsequent development of an extension to support a **full toc** in the sidebar, checkout: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sphinxcontrib-fulltoc

Comment: This works great! But I had to `pip install --upgrade setuptools` first, otherwise it failed to install with a weird error: `AttributeError: '_NamespacePath' object has no attribute 'sort'`

Comment: I currently get this error reported when readthedocs tries to install this.

Comment: @Chris I suspect https://github.com/sphinx-contrib/fulltoc/issues/14 is the cause of this, I'll look into shortly.

Answer (score 4):

Nothing will appear in the "Navigation" section of the default Sphinx sidebar until you **add the names of files that you want to scan for section headings** to the `toctree::` directive in your `.rst` file.

For example, if you want all the headings of your `index.rst` file to appear in the Navigation pane, write `index` (without the extension) in the `toctree::` list like so:

```
My Level 1 Heading
==================

Glorious content.

My Level 2 Heading
------------------

More content


.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2
   :caption: Contents:

   index
```

The crucial bit is adding `index` right there at the end.  If you're like me, you start your projects with the auto-generated template from `sphinx-quickstart`, which (at time of writing) populates your `.rst` files with EMPTY toctrees.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

don't forget the `:hidden:` keyword as shown in that code

```
.. toctree::
    :maxdepth: 1
    :hidden:

    index
    docs/specification
    docs/ux
    docs/database
    docs/techstack
    docs/api
    docs/specialFunctionalities
    enter code here
```