# How to create a title that will not appear in the toctree with Sphinx?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, toctree

I am using Sphinx to create documentation for a Python module.

I wold like to add subtitles on a page but I don't want them to appear in the **toctree**.

I want small sections and short (few lines) descriptions. Adding every section title to the **toctree** would make browsing the docs much harder.

Here is my **index.rst**:

```
Welcome to ModernGL's documentation!
====================================

.. figure:: Examples/images/02_uniforms_and_attributes.png
    :scale: 50 %
    :alt: ModernGL
    :align: center
    :figclass: align-center

Start `here <ModernGL.html>`_.

.. toctree::
    :maxdepth: 4
    :caption: Contents:

    ModernGL <ModernGL.rst>
    Examples <Examples.rst>
    Contributing <Contributing.rst>


Indices and tables
==================

* :ref:`genindex`
* :ref:`modindex`
* :ref:`search`
```

I want to add some subtitles:

```
Subtitle 1
**********

Subtitle 2
**********

Subtitle 3
**********

Subtitle 4
**********
```

I checked the documentation and I have no clue what type of underline should I use. Not sure if there is a special underline that will be convert the title to a `<h4>` or `<h5>`

> With a github **README.md** adding more `#` characters will result in smaller titles. What is the equivalent in ***.rst**?
>
> The build documentation can be found [here](https://moderngl.readthedocs.io/) and it does not contain subtitles since it would ruin the current structure of the docs.

Comment: You could consider using the [Rubric](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#rubric) directive.

Comment: Yes rubric is better then the `^^^^` underline: Here is an example: [rst file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cprogrammer1994/ModernGL/master/docs/ModernGL.rst) and [css file](https://github.com/cprogrammer1994/ModernGL/blob/master/docs/static/css/custom.css#L25)

Comment: You are mixing several things into one question. I would open a separate question for this: "With a github README.md adding more # characters will result in smaller titles. What is the equivalent in *.rst?"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you try to add [`hidden`](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/markup/toctree.html?highlight=hidden) in your `toctree` directive? Something like:

```
.. toctree::
    :maxdepth: 4
    :hidden:
    :caption: Contents:

    ModernGL <ModernGL.rst>
    Examples <Examples.rst>
    Contributing <Contributing.rst>
```

> This will still notify Sphinx of the document hierarchy, but not insert links into the document at the location of the directive – this makes sense if you intend to insert these links yourself, in a different style, or in the HTML sidebar.

As for "section headers" (titles and subtitles) this extract from [official Sphinx documentation](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/rest.html#sections) might give you an answer:

> Normally, there are no heading levels assigned to certain characters as the structure is determined from the succession of headings.

You might try to use `^` character for your subsections to render out the heading you need.

Answer (score 6):

*Timestamp: this answer's sphinx-doc.org excerpts are from May, 2021.*

### Short answer:

> I wold like to add subtitles on a page but I don't want them to appear in the **toctree**.

You're looking for the `.. toctree::` directive's `:titlesonly:` option.

Documentation for `.. toctree::`'s `:titlesonly:` here:

- https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/directives.html#table-of-contents
- Under `Directives` > `Table of contents` > `.. toctree::` > `Additional options` > `titlesonly option`
- Definition -- Quoted Text (from that link)

  > If you want only the titles of documents in the tree to show up, not other
  > headings of the same level, you can use the titlesonly option:
  >
  > ```
  > .. toctree::
  >   :titlesonly:
  >   foo
  >   bar
  > ```

### Details:

I'm assuming that you **do** want all of the `.rst` entries in your example's `.. toctree::` directive to appear in the TOC (table of contents) which Sphinx inserts there, but that you do **not** want any `Section Headers` within these `.rst` files to appear in that TOC.

Documentation for `Section Headers` here:

- https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/basics.html#sections
- Definition -- Quoted text from that link:

  > Section headers ([ref](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#sections)) are created by underlining (and optionally overlining) the section title with a punctuation character, at least as long as the text:
  >
  > ```
  > =================
  > This is a heading
  > =================
  > ```
  >
  > ...
  >
  > - # with overline, for parts
  > - * with overline, for chapters
  > - =, for sections
  > - -, for subsections
  > - ^, for subsubsections
  > - ", for paragraphs

By default, without the `:titlesonly:` option under the `.. toctree::` directive, the rendered TOC tree will display both the "titles" of the listed `.rst` files and also any `Section Headers` listed within these `.rst` files.

Using the `:titlesonly:` option under the `.. toctree::` directive, these "Headings" a.k.a. `Section Headers` will not be rendered in the TOC tree (and only the "titles" of the `.rst` files will be displayed).

---

### Example *without* `:titlesonly:` option:

- If your `.. toctree::` looks like this (**without** the `:titlesonly:` option):
    [image: index.rst, toctree without titlesonly]
- Then the TOC is rendered
  listing both the `.rst` page titles
  and **also** their `Section Headers`:
    [image: html output, toctree without titlesonly]

---

### Example *with* `:titlesonly:` option present:

- If your `.. toctree::` looks like this (**with** the `:titlesonly:` option):
    [image: index.rst, toctree WITH titlesonly]
- Then the TOC is rendered
  listing **only** the `.rst` page titles
  but **not** their contained `Section Headers`:
    [image: html output, toctree WITH titlesonly]

---

### Related, but different scope:

This answer (above) is for the `.. toctree::` directive.

Different steps are required for altering the sidebar, and these steps can be different depending on the custom theme you're using with Sphinx.

If you also want to modify the TOC displayed by the sidebar, here are some related links to help you get started:

- https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#confval-html_sidebars
- https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/faq.html?highlight=sidebar#how-do-i
- https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/theming.html?highlight=sidebar
- so/q/14477396 : [How to expand all the subsections on the sidebar toctree in Sphinx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14477396/how-to-expand-all-the-subsections-on-the-sidebar-toctree-in-sphinx)
- so/q/18969093 : [How to include the toctree in the sidebar of each page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18969093/how-to-include-the-toctree-in-the-sidebar-of-each-page)

(I'd list more details for this, but I'm still investigating. I'm currently looking for a way to (1) display `Section Headers` in the Sidebar TOC using the `sphinx_rtd_theme`, but to (2) *not* display `Section Headers` in the `.. toctree::` inserts.)